# Is it possible that the chemical composition of Greek fire could have been an alkali metal?

Tags: history-of-chemistry, alkali-metals

"Greek fire" was an ancient weapon used by the Greeks noted as being inextinguishable by water. The chemical composition of this weapon has been debated in the historical scholarship; due to the fact that alkali metals such as sodium and potassium ignite when exposed to water, is it possible that the chemical composition of Greek fire included alkali metals to achieve this property?

Comment: They *explode* in water, so no it couldn't, in fact it was something like napalm.

Comment: In a word, no. The electrolytic technology for making elemental alkali metals was far beyond anything the ancient Greeks possessed.

Comment: Regardless of ancient Greece inability to produce alkali metals, these elements cause Coulombic explosion in contact with water, but do not burn under water.

Answer (score 8):

Sodium, potassium, and every other alkali metal react explosively on contact with water. The presence of water, however, was *not* prerequisite for the ignition of Greek fire. This fact is highlighted by the **disproved** hypothesis on Greek fire composition suggesting it was some reaction between water and calcium oxide (CaO), colloquially called "quicklime". This hypothesis is disproved by accounts in the historical literature, specifically by Emperor Leo's account in *Tactica* noting that the substance would be spread directly on the surface of enemy ships and thus (even with trace water on deck) would need to spontaneously ignite without water in order to work.

There are other variables that confound your alkali metal hypothesis. Firstly, the instability of alkali metals to air (through oxide formation and aforementioned blowing up in water) makes the materials difficult to store should they even have been produced at all. The account of alkali metals in the pertinent time period all come from salts and minerals which do not necessarily react the way the unstable metal might. Once bound as a salt, the properties of the metal change drastically.

The alkali metals also have extremely characteristic coloration of their flames; this is due to the **quantization of electronic energy levels in atoms and molecules** which causes substances to emit very specific wavelengths of light upon combustion. This phenomenon is often used for spectacle—like in the coloration of fireworks—and thus would almost certainly have been fervently noted in any historical account on Greek fire; such accounts are absent.

It is generally agreed upon by scholars that Greek fire was—at least primarily—composed of **crude oil** or some distillation thereof. This is consistent with resistance to extinguishing by water as well as the access of civilizations to crude oil at the time: the Byzantines had clear access to naturally occurring wells of crude oil near the Black Sea, and accounts suggest that 1) this oil was called "naphtha" by the Persians, 2) what the Persians called "naphtha" was the same as what the Greeks called "Median oil", and 3) the term "Median fire" was used alternatively to "Greek fire" in some cases.

It is probable that other components like sulfur and resin were added to change the properties of this substance—especially in places where there were similar weapons documented—but no evidence of specific alkali metals or their salts appear there. Regardless, the water-resistance of the flames is almost certainly due to its identity as a derivative of crude oil given the weapon's properties and the resources of Mediterranean/Middle Eastern civilizations at the time.

Answer (score 1):

From a more recent chemistry perspective, so-called 'spontaneous combustion' as detailed, for example, in this incident: ["Spontaneous Combustion of Oily Rags Cause of Lexington Fire"](https://www.mass.gov/news/spontaneous-combustion-of-oily-rags-cause-of-lexington-fire), to quote:

> The fire started in a dumpster against the outside the garage that contained oil soaked rags and empty linseed oil cans, intermingled with wood, paper, cardboard, and other trash.

More extensively and recently with respect to ancient times, per [Bretherick’s Handbook of Chemical Hazards](https://dl.icdst.org/pdfs/files/319223ac5e83bb6a2c66b7b1f996b003.pdf), one finds that "calcium oxide: H2O" is cited as an explosion hazard likely as a heat accelerant as the hydration reaction is reportedly exothermic.

The same sources also cites fine powders (like Milk Powder) after wetting and air exposure, as capable of producing explosive events. More likely here, however, are the reported spontaneous ignition hazards for cellulose and associated dusts of sulfur, wood flour and more generally natural "fuel dust", which would include fine powdered charcoal. Also, "cotton waste soaked in linseed oil", and perhaps, most pertinent "presence of petroleum products, fire and explosion can be spontaneous".

So, I would surmise that the ancient weapon "Greek fire" was a possible composite of crude fuel oil, quicklime, fine charcoal, flour from finely crushed grain and perhaps, even a touch of sulfur, which in the presence of moisture, would form a highly spontaneously combustible product, but even if this is not exactly the "Greek fire" of old, those testing this formulation are advised to exercise extreme caution.